# Angular How to change values with an boolean value in separet components with service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new in Angular I just want to make one simple thing that I'm having a lot of problems, I created two components header and main, in the header there is the toggle button and in the main there is the sidenav and I wanted to make this button in header to hide and show the sidenav in main component on click. I tried some aproeches. At the beggining I realized that I needed to use services because is not child and parent components.

(On Toggle.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ToggleService {
    
        choice = true;
    
        toggle() {
          this.choice = !this.choice;
        }
    }
```

(On Header.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleService } from '../../services/toggle.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myservice: ToggleService) { 
    
  }
  ComponentToggleMenu() {
    this.myservice.toggle();
 }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

(On Header.component.html)

```
<button (click)="ComponentToggleMenu()"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></button>
```

(On Main.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleService } from '../../services/toggle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  boolean = this.myservice.choice;


  constructor(private myservice: ToggleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

(On Main.component.html)

```
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" mode="side" [opened]="boolean">
```

That was the way that I'd like to work, but the funtion it's only change the value in the service and not in main, I tried a lot of things, I saw videos, angular documents, I tried to use subjects , observables, EventEmiter but none of this things works, and I'd like a method that could be work for any value that I wanted to change in any diferent separet component, but i'm seing that this comunication beetwen components it's too hard, should be more easy in my opnion, and yes it's quiet ease to tranfers functions and variables beetwen components using services but make a component change a value in other it's quiet hard, and I'd like to also know if Vue is best in this part.

(updated)
I didn't fix it, but I made the deploy of the app in the Github and here is the link of the depository and deploy.One detail it's in Portuguese but just click in the toggle button, there is 2 buttons toggle, one in the main component that it's working and the another one in the header component that it's not working.
Depository - https://github.com/EltonModellingDesign/Client-Registration-Angular-app
Deploy - https://eltonmodellingdesign.github.io/Client-Registration-Angular-app/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting `boolean = this.myservice.choice`, but it's a primitive value, not a reference to an object. Therefore, `boolean` will not change when `this.myservice.choice` does.

Instead, you should bind the `opened` property in your `mat-sidenav` directly to `myservice.choice`. You'll also need to make `myservice` public so that your template can access it.

```
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" mode="side" [opened]="myservice.choice">
```

Please see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1ctyb?file=src/app/toggle.service.ts) StackBlitz to see a working version that is very similar to your code, but includes my suggestions.

Comment: I tried this aproche, but anyway it didn't change the value in the main component. I took a stackoverflow post explaned why this can't happend in that way. And also I tried this another way, but I don't know how to apply in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426023/angular-view-binding-not-updating-with-simple-boolean

Comment: I've edited my comment to include a StackBlitz, please take a look.

Comment: As i said it's not working this method, even when I change to public. But for better visualization I made the deploy of the app in the GitHub and heres the links. 

Depository - https://github.com/EltonModellingDesign/Client-Registration-Angular-app 
Deploy - https://eltonmodellingdesign.github.io/Client-Registration-Angular-app/

You can see that the button toggle in main component it's working, but the toggle in the header component it's not. Because this method only works in the same component but not in total separeted components.

Comment: I understand your app is not working, but have you had a look at the StackBlitz? Perhaps we can try to identify some differences between your app and mine, as mine is working the way you want it to. I'll also take a look at your application.

Answer (score 0):

`boolean` in `MainComponent` will not be updated because `this.myservice.choice` is not a pointer.

You can directly refer the service value from your template.

```
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" mode="side" [opened]="myservice.choice">
```

And also you have to change `myservice` from `private` to `public` for refering from template.

```
constructor(public myservice: ToggleService) {}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to update the value in `MainComponent` for some reason, you can do it like this.

toggle.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToggleService {
    
  choice$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);  
    
  toggle() {
    this.choice$.next(!this.choice$.value);
  }
}
```

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleService } from '../../services/toggle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  boolean = true

  constructor(private myservice: ToggleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myservice.choice$.subscribe( choice => {
      this.boolean = choice;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: This method of public made my life more ease in case to take variables and functions from services, but anyway it didn't change the value in the main component. I took a stackoverflow post explaned why this can't happend in that way. And also I tried this another way, but I don't know how to apply in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426023/angular-view-binding-not-updating-with-simple-boolean

Comment: I have updated my answer so that you can update the value `boolean` in `MainComponent`.

Comment: even you can use `[opened]="myservice.choice$|async"` (always inject as public the service) and you needn't subscribe

Comment: Well this method I liked, when I change the value manually in choice$ also change the value in component Main, but even so when I use the function toggle in button toggle in header component it's not change or update the value in main component, to hide and show the sidenav, but it changes the value in service but it's not changing in main component using the function.

Comment: I also tried using async and I don't need subscribe anymore, but steel not working.